# How to write a regex in jsp with only numericals and comma

Tags: java, regex, jsp

I want to match all ofthe following:

```
6
60
60,78
60,67,78
```

I tried this:

```
"/[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*/"
```

but it doesn't match any of them.

Comment: The J in JSP stands for Java, so you can use Java regex. But to extract the numbers a simple `s.split("[ ,]+")` will do.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Where do you struggle? We don't write code for you, we help with problems in your code.

Comment: /[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*/

Comment: This is what i tried.Sorry, forgot to mention that. New to coding

Comment: So you are using that inside a script tag and it's javascript? (Split works there too, just replace the quotes by slashes).

Comment: That's not a script tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `/[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*/` (a JavaScript regular expression), you need to use Java syntax and you can use a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (for efficiency, or [`String.matches(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) if you want to test a *regular expression*). For any `String` starting with one or digits followed by any number of optional comma separated digits you can use something like `^\\d+[,\\d]*$`; as in

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+[,\\d]*$");
String[] inputs = { "60", "60,78", "60,67,78" };
for (String input : inputs) {
    if (p.matcher(input).matches()) {
        System.out.printf("%s matches%n", input);
    }
}
```

I get (as expected)

```
60 matches
60,78 matches
60,67,78 matches
```

If you want make sure there is at least one digit after every comma you could (from the comments below) use a *regular expression* like `^\\d+(,\\d+)*$`.

Comment: This also matches `1,,,,`. Probably not what OP wants.

Comment: I would suggest to use the pattern `"^\\d+(,[\\d]+)*$"` instead.

Comment: @DarkDust Agreed, except there's no need to keep the `[]`.

Comment: If using `matches()`, there's no need for `^` and `$`. They are unnecessary, since `matches()` is explicitly defined to match the *entire* input. Since you don't care about capturing anything, use a non-capturing block. `\\d+(?:,\\d+)*`

Answer (score 1):

Java ain't JavaScript. Java doesn't delimit regex with slashes - remove them:

```
if (input.matches("\\d+(,\\d+)*"))
```

I replaced `[0-9]` with the built-in character class `\d` - it's shorter to write and IMHO easier to read.